# Android Biometric callbacks are not working witn PIN-CODE

Tags: android, kotlin, biometrics

I am trying to implement the biometric with both fingerprint and Pincode, fingerprint is working fine, but when I try to use a pin code, a screen with a pin code is appear but the callbacks are not called, if I call the pin code check without fingerprint just onAuthenticationSucceeded is called,onAuthenticationError and onAuthenticationFailed no, if I call pincode check after fingerprint no one callback called at all, I tied to use one BiometricPrompt for both and separate for each but situation the same, what can be the problem?

```
                    val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Authenticate")
                    .setSubtitle("Use PIN to authenticate")
                    .setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                    .build()

                val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this@SplashActivity, object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                        // Authentication succeeded, handle the result here
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, "AUTH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()

                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                        // Authentication error, handle the error here
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, "ERR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        // Authentication failed, handle the failure here
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                })

                biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. In our case even the activity which triggered the biometric prompt authentication is "killed" after the PIN has been entered  haven't yet figured out why.

Comment: I figured out that we have the problem with Huawei and Xiaomi devices. Works fine on Google Pixel. In the logs I also see that on the Huawei device our underlying activity gets destroyed as soon as we start the biometric authentication.
On which devices did you tried it?

Comment: @Aaron the problem is I have that issue on Pixel 7 pro

Comment: I solved my problem. In my case it relates to creating the `PendingIntent`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75940579/5284698 Have a look. May be it helps.