# Device credential (PIN) using BiometricPrompt destroys calling activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-biometric-prompt

we are currently facing a weird `BiometricPrompt` behaviour on some Android devices.
The problem is brand/manufacturer independent because it works e.g. on some Samsung devices but on others doesn't.

## The Issue

To approve some transaction made by the user to her account we require her to authenticate herself using her device credentials or biometry.
Under the hood we are using `BiometricPrompt`.
The problem we are facing is that immediately after calling the `BiometricPrompt.authenticate()` method the device credential screen is shown (specifically only PIN), our underlying activity gets destroyed (there are just some milliseconds in between), we enter the Pin-Code, click continue, the device credential screens disappears and we see the home screen of the device itself.
The problem only occurs while the users has set up a PIN as device credential.
Pattern and biometry are working fine.
Also, PIN is working on some other Android devices.

## Code

Here is the code we are calling:

```kotlin
suspend fun authenticate(
    activity: FragmentActivity
): AuthenticationResult = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION") // We are aware of this. If possible we use the "Modern" approach.
    val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.biometric_prompt_title))
        .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
        .build()
    activity.createBiometricPrompt(continuation).authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

Our `authenticate()` method is called on the main thread using `Dispatchers.Main`.

Here is the code of the `createBiometricPrompt()` method:

```kotlin
fun FragmentActivity.createBiometricPrompt(continuation: Continuation<AuthenticationResult>): BiometricPrompt {
    return BiometricPrompt(
        this,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                continuation.resume(AuthenticationResult.Error(errorCode, errString))
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                continuation.resume(AuthenticationResult.Succeeded(result))
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                Timber.i("onAuthenticationFailed")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Since we are sending a push to the device which is registered as the second factor we create a `PendingIntent` to present the transaction activity.
We create the activity with the following code:

```kotlin
fun createPendingIntent(context: Context, transaction: Transaction): PendingIntent =
    Intent(context, TransactionActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
        putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_TRANSACTION_APPROVAL, transaction)
    }.let { intent ->
        val flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1484, intent, flags)
    }
```

We use the same code during login.
There our code works without any issues on all devices.
Therefore my guess that we might do something wrong creating the `Intent`/`PendingIntent`?

Does any of you has an idea what might cause our problem?

## Already tried solutions

- Added logs to our activity. Can confirm that `onDestroy` of our activity is called
- removed all `flags` from `Intent`

Comment: I've already found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800574/android-biometric-callbacks-are-not-working-witn-pin-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution to my problem.
Regarding the documentation here [Start an Activity from a Notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation) they recommend using `TaskStackBuilder` to build your `PendingIntent`.
Using `TaskStackBuilder` our activity isn't killed while the PIN screen gets/is shown.